# couchbase defaulting to localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, couchbase

I'm using .NET Core 2 (C#) in a web api project.   I've looked at many things online to use couchbase with it but for some reason the configuration always keeps pointing to localhost.

appsettings.json

```
    "Couchbase" : {
  "Servers": [
    "http://myserver.com:8091"
  ],
  "UseSsl": false
}
```

startup.cs

```
          services
            .AddCouchbase(Configuration.GetSection("Couchbase"))
            .AddCouchbaseBucket<IRdsBucketProvider>(bucket, password);
```

There is nothing in my code to tell it to connect to couchbase on localhost but it still does.   Any ideas?   I've searched for a few days about this.

Comment: check that `Configuration.GetSection("Couchbase")` returns expected data. Localhost may be just the default fallback value.

Comment: I'm trying it locally, and it appears to be working as expected, based on the JSON you supplied. I can think of 2 questions to try and narrow it down: first, the "Couchbase" in appsettings.json is at root level, right? Second, how do you know it's using localhost? If you're seeing writes show up locally, for instance, then maybe post the code you're using to do those writes.

Comment: My "Couchbase" section wasn't in the root of appsettings.json.   It is working now.   How I knew it was falling back was because I had different data in the document on my local machine.  So I stopped the couchbase service on my local machine and then it was blowing up every time I tried to connect to a bucket.   So it must fall back to localhost if another server is not found or in my case the GetSection was returning null because my section was in the wrong place.